# TS2304: Cannot find name 'Router'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I'm having some trouble redirecting to a certain page in my Angular 2 Ionic app. I have followed the following example: https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview . Yet I cannot seem to get it working as I keep getting this error: 'TS2304 Cannot find name 'Router''

My IDE shows the error on the 'Router' keyword in the constructor() line 12.

My code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {BackandService} from '@backand/angular2-sdk';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'user_auth.html',
  selector: 'page-user-auth',
})
export class UserAuthPage {

  constructor(private backand: BackandService, public router: Router) {
    this.backand.user.getUserDetails().then(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res.data) {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.router.navigate('/login');
        }
      },
      (err: any) => {
        null;
      }
    );
  }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Too late I realized; if you're working with Ionic framework, you should use the [Ionic navigation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) instead of Angular 2 routing. This helped me further eventually.

Comment: i think you forgot to save plunker...

Comment: The eg. is  backdated. Now you need to use the RouterModule, and configure it with the routes. In your root module, declare as RouterModule.forRoot(Routes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue :

```
 this.router.navigate('/login');
```

should be

```
 this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? @Vivek Doshi is right that the `router.navigate` parameter requires an array and not a string.

Comment: @snaplemouton, thanks :) , don't know who downvoted this answer.

Comment: Hi Vivek, this turns out to be a part of the solution. I tried reinstalling (installing latest version) @angular/router and, together with adding the square brackets, provided the solution :) Thanks!

Comment: @pieterjanvdp  will you please also upvote the answer, please?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I did, but as I have less than 15 reputation my vote is not shown publicly